# Lookup from HashMap based on expression

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, hashcode

```
class Expression{
   private final String expression; //can be 00* or 01* or 0101*

   public int hashCode(){
       //what should I put here
       //tried to use String hashCode but not useful
   }

   public boolean equals(Object obj){
       //Logic for testing of equality
       //Check if the obj is String check if expression matches
   }
}

//This is how map is initialized
map.put("00*",someObject);
map,put("0101*", someOtherObject);
```

**Why the String hashCode implementation was not useful?**

Because the `String` in the `Expression` class is `00*` and the `String` that I am trying to lookup will be `00112233`. So the `hashCode()` won't be same for those Strings.

Client code tries to lookup from the `HashMap` using `String` key

```
map.get("0011"); //should get someObject as `0011` matches expression `00*`
```

Is there any way to do this?

I know that `hashCode()` should contain values that are immutable and about the `hashCode()` and `equals()` contract.

But I am doubtful if there is any way to achieve this.

Comment: inside the implementation you can validate what you want using regular expression and then add to the Hashmap if it satisfies your condition.

Comment: @AurA map is already initialized with expressions. And now I want to check the entries based on which string satisfies a particular expression and use that value from map.

Comment: @mvw I have added the explanation for that. Check the updated answer.

Comment: @NarendraPathai I missed the word "regular expression" in your question.

Comment: What if "0011" matches "00*" and "001*"?

Comment: @bellabax exactly my thought. He could enumerate his regexps and use the number of that regexp as a hash code, but then those regular expressions need not be overlapping (a string should match utmost one reg exp). And here 01* and 0101* overlap (0101 will match both).

Comment: @bellabax Yes that would be taken care of. Regular expressions will not be overlapping.

Answer (score 0):

There is a reason there is no implementation of such a data-structure.
Lets reverse engineer it:

**Requirements:**

```
keyA = Expression.getInstance("00*");
keyB = Expression.getInstance("0011");

map.get(keyA) == map.get(keyB)
```

*Now how does hashmap() work?*

- First, key's hash value is calculated, which is used to locate the hash bucket.
- Now with that bucket key's equals() is used to find the Entry object and then Entry.value() is returned.

**Anaysis**

So that means, `keyA` and `keyB` should have same *hashCode* and should be *equal* as well.

so `keyA.equals(keyB) == true`

What about, `keyC = Expression.getInstance("0010");`

According to your logic `keyC.equals(keyA) = true`. But because equals is transitive that means `keyB.equals(keyC) == true`.

That means in your map, `0010` and `0011` map to the same value!? Infact anything starting with "00" will have the same value. So, its same as using `00` as the key for that value.
You see where I am going?

In short, I don't see it working on an existing HashMap() implementation.

Comment: If I have not misunderstood you too are suggesting that it ain't possible, right?

Comment: Not via standard hashCode() and equals() methods.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with RocketBoy .. this will not work with a `Map`. I'd suggest looking at the `Trie` datatype. It's not in the standard Java API, so you'll need to write your own implementation or find one online.

Another option would be keeping a `List<Expression>` in addition to your `Map`. You could loop through the list doing something like

```
for (final Expression e : myExpressions) {
    if (myLookup.startsWith(e)) {
        return myMap.get(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me restate your problem:

You have n regular expressions over L={0,1}^*

```
re_1
re_2
..
re_n
```

and you have stored your objects in a hash map with the strings of the regular expressions (or number) as key.

```
map.put(re_1, obj_1)
map.put(re_2, obj_2)
..
map.put(re_n, obj_n)
```

Now you have a given string s matching (utmost) one of the regular expressions and you want a fast

```
map.get(s) -> s matching regexp re_k -> map.get(re_k) -> obj_k
```

This will need a way to identify which regular expression it is that your given string s matches.

The easiest way is a loop over the set of all n regular expressions, trying one after another, if your strings matches it.

Any more clever scheme would need to analyze the given regular expressions, most likely the graphs of their equivalent finite automata.

I don't know such a scheme.

It also depends on your regular expressions, maybe they have some easy shape, which can be exploited.